recover deleted firestore collection
I accidentally deleted firestore collection. then I interuppted that in between and it resulted in partial  deletion. I want to restore my data.
Point in time recovery was not enabled and I made above mistake how can I restore that back?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you didn't enable point-in-time recovery and didn't schedule database backups, there is no way to recover the deleted data.

yeah that's what support team told me, But I was just checking if there is any way they are storing something. They do store the count of read/write/operations but not the deleted items

I know what you asked, which is why I answered that the information isn't kept unless you've used either of the features. --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?
